# Fundamentals question: Django + Python Virtual Env + pyCharm and CLI -- are two separate virtual environments required?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

Bottom Line: 
I can get everything to work by configuring two separate virtual environments, one for pyCharm and one for the CLI.  Is this really necessary or should I be able to use 1 virtual environment for both as I expected?

More Detailed explanation:

I'm very new so this is probably a facepalm type of question so i'll try to be terse.
I'm using Linux Mint, Python 3.6, django 3.0.3, and pyCharm 2019.3.1.

I can create a virtual env using venv in the cli and it works.
I can also create a NEW virtual env in pyCharm through the settings: Project: Interpreter interface, and it works, however it doesn't have venv as an option, it only has virtualenv.

But if I try to activate the virtual env i created in pyCharm from the cli (using virtualenv of course, not venv), it fails hard and thinks i'm using python 2.7 which isn't even installed on my system.  If it try to point pyCharm at the virtual env I setup on the cli, I get an error 134.

Is this just a known/expected issue?  Must I have two virtual environments for every project I want to access via both pyCharm AND the cli?  And I assume this is unrelated but I also find it odd that pyCharm lists my interpreter as python 3.7, which also is not installed on my system.   I'm using 3.6 alone.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you choosing the right python version when create virtual env in pycharm? It asks for a python path when you create it and it should point to python3.

Comment: Please add more details, at least how you were trying to add existent venv and what was the description for error 134.

Comment: Thank you, but i was intentionally trying to word this in such a way as to be considerate of folks time -- what i mean by that is I was hoping someone could tell me if I wasted 4 hours of my time trying to point both the CLI and pyCharm at the same virt env when there is some obvious reason I'm unaware of that precludes me from doing such a thing.  If instead everyone said, "yeah that shouldn't be a problem." then I was prepared to dig deeper before possibly reaching out for more help with the specific errors, etc.  Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @Glyphack For the pyCharm interpreter I am "creating new" and pointing it my base python interpreter (which it shows as 3.7 despite my not having 3.7 installed, only 3.6).  For the CLI I am simply using  "python -m venv" and then confirming with whichpython and python -version that I am on the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I'm going to just answer this as: you need a separate virtual env for each (pyCharm and CLI) as this approach is not difficult or time-consuming and I have not had any issues working in this way.